# extracting data from external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html file containing only a table with data (it's an MS access table exported). I also have a main page in which I have a table, initially empty.
I want to, using pure javascript if possible (if it's not, I can use jquery) extract the table data from the first file, in the background, and feed the table in the second file with it.
I've seen some possible solutions, but none cover exactly what I need.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript can do anything that jQuery can... faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get( "external_html_file.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".main_page_table" ).html( data );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".main_page_table").load("external_html_file.html")
```